# What versions of RHEL support Amazon Corretto?

Tags: java, rhel, corretto

What versions of RHEL 6 and 7 will run Corretto 8 or 11?  The Corretto FAQ (aws.amazon.com/corretto/faqs) states Linux builds are supported on RHEL 6+.  But Amazon's March 19, 2019 Intro to Amazon Corretto Tech Talk (www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTqhPvyAsfQ and on Amazon's Corretto site) says RHEL 7+.

Answer (score 0):

The Corretto [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/faqs/) would prevail. Both Corretto 8 and 11 are supported on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6+.